# How to calculate user distance using Wifi signals?

Tags: android, dictionary, android-wifi, indoor-positioning-system

I am making my own indoor map for a shopping mall. I am making it on android. Please guide me about how to calculate user distance through Wifi signals and move location pin/pointer on map.

Comment: I have heard that, for a fee, google will come out and do their street view images but of the inside of your location. That could be helpful along with your mapping.

Comment: I have changed my question as my old question was too broad but now I am asking question in a particular domain please help me !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think again before ruling out Google Maps API.

Google Maps API v2 added support to indoor maps. in fact, Google Maps also
allows you to [upload your own indoor maps](https://support.google.com/gmm/answer/1685872?hl=en&topic=1685871&ctx=topic) to be interleaved with their service.

If that doesn't work for you check [Insiteo's product](http://www.insiteo.com/joomla/index.php/en/). I have tested it for a project I was involved in and was rather impressed.

Finally remember that even the best indoor map solution will not provide you with a decent experience 
unless you can back it with an accurate indoor positioning system.

You probably want to start your search with Google's [fused location provider](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) (select PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).
Some people say its indoors performance is not as good as the team claims, but they keep improving it 
all the time so I cannot really tell.

Gilad